# Fastest way to display a frame in game

Tags: c++, c

I'm create a game using `system("cls")` and `printf`.
I have a two-dimension array of character for the field.
I refresh the screen every 0.5 sec and display the whole field but the screen flashes badly.
Is there anyway I could make it smooth.
My OS is Windows.

Comment: On which operating system? On Linux, consider using `ncurses` library. And you could make your game graphical, e.g. use a toolkit like `Qt` or `Gtk` (both being cross-platform)...

Comment: There is no way. Games just are like that on Windows. That's why people prefer to play games on consoles, which don't have `cls`.

Comment: Your main issue is the `cls` which clears the screen - this causes the flicker. Depending on your system/console, you can use some escape characters to position the cursor to the home position and simply reprint (overwrite) everything without clearing it. Libraries like ncurses encapsulate this in a more convenient API. For Windows, you might consider [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you want using the Win32 console window functions: Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx Have a browse through there for how to set the cursor position and write text. You can also set text colours etc if you need a distraction from coding better gameplay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ncurses (or pdcurses, might be easier to set up on Windows.) If you can't, then don't clear the screen, as that causes flicker. Instead, position the cursor to the top-left (0, 0) again and then draw.  To position the cursor at 0, 0, you can do:

```
#include <windows.h>
// ...
HANDLE handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
COORD position = {0, 0};
SetConsoleCursorPosition(handle, position);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to [create a second screen buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can write directly to this, as it's not visible. When you have a new frame ready, swap the visible buffer with this second buffer. This instantly displays the new frame, and you can now draw in the original buffer.

This technique is widely used and is known as *double buffering*.